# All I want in a Rich Text Editor is bold, italic, and links. Is there anything out there?

Tags: richtextbox, text-editor, richtextediting

I'm working on a small web application that will let users enter calendar events. For the description of the event, I would like them to be able to do the following:

- Set bold text
- Set italic text
- Create a link
- Absolutely nothing else

For example, if someone tries to paste "Nasty Hot Pink Text" from Word, I don't want that to work the way their devious little minds want it to :).

So far I've tried the YUI Rich Text Editor and TinyMCE, but I haven't been able to turn off enough of the features to make me comfortable with them. I can get TinyMCE to strip out everything on save, but it still shows the formatting at design time. That seems like bad usability to me. Plus, the YUI editor doesn't output XHTML.

I think the Markdown editor comes closest to the feature set that I want, but I think the lack of WYSIWYG would be confusing to people.

Anybody have a solution?

Comment: TinyMCE is *very* customizable.  What features weren't you able to strip out?

Comment: I don't want any of the font size, color, etc. features to display when people are using the editor. This is because I have it customized to strip out all span and font tags upon save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I'm going to be going with TinyMCE, but nobody actually posted that as an answer! If you have the **paste** plugin enabled, it does strip out formatting.

Answer (score 1):

i think SPAW editor is a good choice here take a look at demos here :
http://www.spaweditor.com/spaw/demo/demo.php

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't SO have this editor I am typing in as an open-source project?

A forked version of the WMD editor, available from [Dana Robinson's git repository](http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master).

Thought I read it in the blog

Answer (score 0):

The [FCKEditor](http://www.fckeditor.net/) is my favorite web Editor.

You can customize the toolbar to give as much or as little as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, http://cheeaun.github.com/mooeditable/ can pretty much only do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is [markItUp! Universal markup editor](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

"markItUp! is a lightweight JavaScript plugin built on the jQuery library. It allows you to turn any textarea into a markup editor. Html, Textile, Wiki Syntax, Markdown, BBcode or even your own Markup system can be easily implemented."